# Laravel - Can't delete a record with many-to-many relation, 'Call to undefined method getForeignKey()'

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have two models, `Training` and `User`. Both have many-to-many relations between themselves. When I try to delete a user, I get this error message:

```
Call to undefined method Roche\Trainings\Facades\TrainingFacade::getForeignKey()
```

This is my `User` model `trainings()` method:

```
public function trainings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'Training' );
}
```

and this is my `UsersController` `postDelete` method:

```
public function postDelete( $user )
{
    // Check if we are not trying to delete ourselves
    if ( $user->id === \Confide::user()->id )
    {
        // Redirect to the user management page
        return Redirect::to( 'admin/users' )->with( 'error', Lang::get( 'admin/users/messages.delete.impossible' ) );
    }

    \AssignedRoles::where( 'user_id', $user->id )->delete();

    $id = $user->id;

    $user->trainings()->detach();

    $user->delete();

    $user = User::find( $id );

    if ( empty( $user ) )
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.delete.success'));
    }
    else
    {
        // There was a problem deleting the user
        return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.delete.error'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it supposed to use the TrainingFacade as model?

Comment: @lukasgeiter it isn't, I have just discovered the problem. I'll answer my own question in a second. Thank you for pointing out the problem.